# Redshift UDF logical issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, user-defined-functions

I am trying to write a redshift udf to validate timestamp. But, it always returns false. Can some explain why?

```
create or replace function f_Is_timestamp_sql(VARCHAR(20000))
  returns timestamp  
  STABLE
as $$
       select $1::timestamp as a;
$$ language sql;

create or replace function f_Is_timestamp(val VARCHAR(20000))
  returns bool
IMMUTABLE 
as $$
    try:
       (f_Is_timestamp_sql(val));  
    except:
       return (1==2);
    else:
      return 1==1;
$$ language plpythonu;

select f_Is_timestamp('2019-10-09')
```

Comment: Could you please clarify how you intend to use this function? Are you passing a string to the function and you want to know if it casts successfully to a `TIMESTAMP`? Your example is a `DATE`, not a `TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: Yes, I intend to check whether passed string can be casted to timestamp. Though it is a date, it can still be casted to a timestamp isn't it? This returs false even for this 
select f_Is_timestamp('2019-10-09 00:00:00')

Comment: I wonder if you can simply do something like `return ($1::timestamp)::varchar == $1`? That will check whether it is the same value when cast into a timestamp and back to a string.

Comment: I understand the logic that you are trying to use. However, I wanted write a generic function that converts to timestamp from any format. "select '01-jANUARY-2019 01:01:01'::timestamp" this works in redshift. But as per your logic it wouldn't work. Am I right?

Comment: Perhaps check that `$1::timestamp` results in a non-empty timestamp value? Are you sure that an invalid value would cause an exception in the UDF?

Comment: Yes, I ran this and got result
select f_Is_timestamp_sql('2019-january-09 00:00:00'. And regarding the exception being caught, i have written similar udf to check for integer value and exception is getting caught. with this function, it always results as an exception which is why the result is false.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204869/discussion-between-mani-bharataraju-and-john-rotenstein).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading thru the AWS documents, I figured out that a UDF cannot reference the contents of another UDF.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/udf-python-language-support.html
Therefore, my function always throws an exception. I figured out an alternative way to accomplish this using python library

```
dateutil.parser
```

Working function below.

```
create or replace function f_Is_timestamp(val VARCHAR(20000))
  returns bool
IMMUTABLE 
as $$
    from dateutil.parser import parse;
    try:
        parse(val,ignoretz=True);
    except:
        return 1==2;
    else:
        return 1==1;
$$ language plpythonu;
```

Comment: In Python, you can `return True` and `return False`.