# How to check if '20210228' is a valid date?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, user-defined-functions

I'd like to check valid date value or not by UDF in Redshift.

Check Value can be both of character and date (date format text), for example, '20210228' or '2021-02-28'.

Following UDF works fine for date format character, yyyy-mm-dd, '2021-02-28', as expected.

But this is not working for date format character yyyymmdd, '20210228'.

```
select isdate('2021-02-28') ;   --> returned 1, it's working.
select isdate('2021-02-29') ;   --> returned 0, it's working.

select isdate('20210228') ;    
  --> returned 0, it's not working as argument format is yyyymmdd, not yyyy-mm-dd

select isdate(substring('20210228', 1,4) || '-' || substring('20210228', 5,2) || '-' ||  substring('20210228', 7,2)) 
 --> returned 1, it's working, but bit noisy.
```

If anyone has any better idea to improve following UDF, any advice would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
-- function 
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION isdate (x1 varchar) 
RETURNS float 
IMMUTABLE as $$
  import datetime
  try:
    datetime.datetime.strptime(x1, '%Y-%m-%d')
    return True
  except ValueError:
    return False 
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

Referred from: [Amazon Redshift Validate Date - isdate Function - DWgeek.com](https://dwgeek.com/amazon-redshift-validate-date-isdate-function.html/).

---

Thanks to the suggestion by @John Rotenstein, following answer is perfect for me -- now, both of character and date (date format text) checked successfully as I expected.

Redshift UDF logical issue
[Redshift UDF logical issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59485574/redshift-udf-logical-issue)

```
-- revised function 
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION isdate2 (x1 varchar) 
  returns bool
IMMUTABLE 
as $$
    from dateutil.parser import parse;
    try:
        parse(x1,ignoretz=True);
    except:
        return 1==2;
    else:
        return 1==1;
$$ language plpythonu;
```

2020 is a leap year, so returns true.
2021 is not a leap year, so returns false.

```
select isdate2('20200229');  --> returned true, 
select isdate2('20210229');  --> returned false 

select isdate2('2020-02-29');  --> returned true
select isdate2('2021-02-29');  --> returned false
```

Thank you so much to let me know the prefect reference, John, you saved me again!!

Comment: Your function uses the dateformat `'%Y-%m-%d'`, so obviously it is not going to work for a date with format `'%Y%m%d'`. You either need to check multiple formats, or you need to make the format configurable.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and edit, @Mark Rotteveel. I revised my UDF using parse and it's working fine now. Thank you so much. Guys here always help me.